# What is the best way to implement the coin contract to get all coin transaction history?

Tags: contract-design

What is the best way to implement the coin contract code to see all transaction history?

It's easy to get the transaction history of ether, but it's kind of difficult to get all sending and receiving history of coin contract.

1. Add event log in sending function
2. Parse all messages to the coin contract

Any other ways?